# How to use Meteor.wrapAsync with an EventEmitter?

Tags: meteor

How would I use Meteor.wrapAsync to wrap the following code.

```
 var csv = require("fast-csv");
 csv
 .fromPath("my.csv")
 .on("data", function(data){
     console.log(data);
 })
 .on("end", function(){
     console.log("done");
 });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the CSV data is small enough to fit in memory:

```js
var parseCsvFromFile = Meteor.wrapAsync(function (filename, callback) {
  var result = [];
  csv.fromPath(filename)
     .on("data", function (row) { result.push(row); })
     .on("end", function () { callback(null, result); });
});

// usage:
var csvData = parseCsvFromFile(/* ... */);
```

`Meteor.wrapAsync` takes a function which accepts a node-style `(err, results)` callback, and returns a synchronous function. So it's necessary to write a function which consumes `fast-csv`'s event-emitter and provides an `(err, results)` callback interface for `wrapAsync` to convert.

A complete solution would also handle errors from `fast-csv`.